# how field specifier works in C

Tags: c

I need to take two int values from user. First value is using field specifier and second is normal integer value.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num, num1;
    printf("Enter first number: \n");
    scanf("%2d", &num);
    printf("First number is %2d\n", num);

    printf("Enter second number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Second number is %d\n", num1);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is

```
Enter first number: 
12345
First number is 12
Enter second number: 
Second number is 345
```

It won't give control to enter second number. I don't know why?

Comment: the second number is ALREADY in the stdin buffer, so the user doesn't need to do anything more, as the user has already entered the second number.  Remember, the first scanf %2d is only going to consume 2 digits.  That leaves the following three digits available for the second scanf %d to consume.

Comment: BTW:  it is always a good idea to check the returned values from input functions (like scanf()) to assure the input/conversion was successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't get to enter second num because your program gets it from first num.

First time, your scanf lets your num get first two digits of the number you entered, and rest remains in the buffer/stream. 
next time scanf is executed, it reads the remaining digits from the stream till an enter stroke, hence you don't get to enter the second no.

if you want to read the second no.
try flushing the stream before using second scanf(), you will get what you want.

Comment: If you by flushing mean calling fflush, that would be undefined behaviour. It works as expected on some platforms, though.

Comment: I know there is no standard way to discard unread characters from a stdio input stream, fflush may or may not work at someplaces, but I'll suggest the OP to go with work-arounds in case fflush doesn't work at his platform

Answer (score 5):

You see this behaviour because you have limited the size of input that the first scanf statement can consume. `scanf("%2d", &num)` says that [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) should read a field of width at most `2` and convert that into into `num`.

Change the `scanf` to `scanf("%d", &num)` and the entirety of `12345` will be processed.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you expect it to "give control"? The fist scanf() explicitly consumed at most two digits, leaving "345" unconsumed. The next scan begins with the unconsumed input. What else would you expect?

If you want to discard any unconsumed input before the next scan, use fpurge(stdin).

Comment: fpurge is non-standard, and might not be present on your platform.

Comment: And if fpurge() is not present, you can write your own.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a tradeoff with `scanf`. If you want to enter a **whole number** and then consume the trailing `newline` (left in the `input buffer (stdin)` as the result of pressing `[enter]`), you canappend a `%*c` to **read and discard** the trailing newline. This itself causes problems if an empty-string is entered.

However, limiting your `scanf format string and specifier` to `%2d` and then entering `123456`, you intentially leave `3456\n` in the `input buffer` which is taken as **your input** to the second `scanf` call. The only way to insure each of your `scanf` calls will only accept your expected input is to manually empty the `input buffer` after each read by `scanf` to insure there are no characters remaining prior to the next call. A simple way to do this is with either a `do .. while` or simply a `while ;` using `getchar()` to read each character in `stdin` until a `'\n'` is encountered or `EOF`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c, num, num1;
    printf("Enter first number: \n");
    scanf("%2d", &num);
    while ((c = getchar()) && c != '\n' && c  != EOF) ;
    printf("First number is %2d\n", num);

    printf("Enter second number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Second number is %d\n", num1);
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_tradeoff
Enter first number:
123456
First number is 12
Enter second number:
12345
Second number is 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for second value is not getting from you, in first scanf you are mentioning that
get the two values from the input. You are giving more than two that time the remaining value is stored in the buffer. So second scanf will get the value from the buffer.

If you want to  avoid this you can use this statement before the second scanf.

```
 while ((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF);// clearing the buffer.
```

So now the second input will get from the user.

Comment: What happens if `stdin` is at `EOF` when you enter that loop? (much better `:)`